# Does the air pressure inside a box remain the same after it is sealed?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

Let's assume that the pressure is 1 atm outside the sealed box. I think that the pressure inside the box will be the same at 1 atm. But why?

Isn't the giant column of air above causing pressure stopped when I seal the box?

Comment: Are you asking whether the pressure of air inside an open rigid vessel _changes_ when the opening is sealed?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Assuming you simply sealed the box while the air inside is at atmospheric pressure, then yes, it will stay that way.

Why: Without getting too into the weeds: microscopically, pressure is the result of the little air molecules bouncing against a surface. In this case, the surface is the side of a box. Each molecule bouncing imparts a small amount of force. If roughly equal particles bounce against both sides of that box side in a given time, the side doesn't move in either direction.

**If we simply enclose a parcel of air inside of a boundary without squeezing it or doing anything to it, the same number of particles are in that volume as before and on average will continue hitting the inside and outside of any given side at the same rate as before (or passing a boundary if there's no physical barrier to stop them). Individual particles will not be able to enter or leave the parcel, but since the average number of particles bouncing against either side stay the same, we get the same pressure.**

---

How many particles bounce against the side is governed by how many particles there are in the volume. So more particles -> more bounces -> more pressure. So if we have the same pressure on the inside and outside, we have roughly the same number of bounces on both sides, so the sides don't bulge inward or outward. See further down for a little math that backs this up.

Since the box sides themselves just respond to the bounces on both sides, the air column is still weighing down on the box, but keep in mind that the box is trying to "weigh down" the air inside of it as well, and that air inside is pushing back, which holds up the box, which holds up the air (this is newton's third law "every action has an equal and opposite reaction").

**Yes, the atmosphere is pressing against the box from at least the top (and probably the sides as well, assuming they're exposed to the atmosphere). But don't forget that the air inside the box is *also* pressing back out against the sides of the box, balancing the inward force from the air outside.**

Think of any given parcel of air as being "boxed in" on all sides". The air column pushes down on top, but the parcel can't go anywhere, because there's already air in those places blocking it from going into those spaces. The other air parcels are also likewise boxed in, so they can't really go anywhere either. Of course, individual particles can communicate between these parcels, since there's not a real boundary. For every particle that goes one way, another particle slides into the vacated spot, possibly from another parcel. If a real boundary did suddenly happen (for instance, we put a cap on a flat tire), the particles simply wouldn't be able to move between parcels, but the overall number of particles in a parcel would remain the same.

[image]

---

Fact: $$\text{Area of the side of the inside of the box} = \text{Area of the side on the outside of the box}$$ $$\text{Force}=\text{Pressure}*\text{Area}$$

Since $P_\text{inside} = P_\text{outside}$ and $A_\text{inside} = A_\text{outside}$, then $$F_\text{inside} = F_\text{outside}$$ for each side. Which means that the box isn't going to collapse because the forces from the air inside and outside balance out.

If you're wondering about what's supporting the column of air outside of the box, if you seal 1 Atm of air inside it, then that air inside is what's supporting it (it's basically like a solid block as far as the air column cares). The box itself only contains the volume, and doesn't provide any support here, per se.

If the box were sealed with a vacuum inside (0 Atm), and the box were strong enough not to collapse, then that means the physical material of the box itself is supporting the air column. That situation is a little different. You'd have to have a pretty strong box, otherwise you get things like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz95_VvTxZM

Answer (score 0):

Before you sealed the box, the air inside and outside could communicate (exchange pressure waves), and so the pressure everywhere was 1 atm.  If there were any minute differences, they would have exchanged pressure waves and the gas would have moved until it equalized.
Once you seal the box, however, they both begin at 1 atm, but nothing is actively keeping them the same (if the walls are rigid), since pressure waves can no longer travel across the boundary.  If a change occurred, such as the box heating or cooling, or else ambient atmosphere dropping from 1 atm to .999 atm due to weather, the two pressures would be different.
This is the case for any air tank, scuba tank, or even your house to a extent.  Ventilation systems must be designed to allow the inside and outside to exchange air appropriately with temperature and weather swings, or else pressure imbalances would develop that could break walls or other structure.